# Craft 3 Redactor Link no longer has target option

Tags: craft3, redactor, wysiwyg

The option for opening a link in the Redactor WYSIWYG no longer includes a field for opening it in a new tab? I haven't been able to find any docs that indicate any options for the Redactor config file to add this back in?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @jolyonruss Did you try looking here? There should be a .js file. In my case on Craft 2, it's here. /resources/lib/redactor/redactor.js [![Redactor Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cBC8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cBC8.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the [linkNewTab](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/link/#s-linknewtab) config option to the Redactor config you're using:
So, that would become something like:

```
{
    "buttons": [...],
    "plugins": [...],
    "linkNewTab": true
}
```

Comment: Top man. Really helpful. I did have a look through the docs but clearly missed that. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Paul - I'm trying to configure Redactor in the same way but am not having any luck. I found a Simple.json and Standard.json files in /config/redactor/. Is this the correct place to make the changes? Is there anything I need to do after making the changes before the field will show up?